# How to route or use iptables to forward one server port to client on different subnet

Tags: iptables, routing, linux-networking, forwarding

The setup (all is linux):

```
client IP address: 192.168.2.15 (interface eth1)
box IP address: 192.168.2.2 (interface eth1)
box IP address: 192.168.101.11 (interface eth0)
server IP address: 192.168.101.12 (interface eth0)
```

The client needs to access the server via port 2300 but is on a different subnet. *How do I configure iptables so that the client accepts box as the server on its subnet?* In other words how do I route traffic between client and server so that:

Outgoing:

```
192.168.2.15 -> 192.168.2.2 ==> 192.168.101.11 -> 192.168.101.12 (all port 2300)
```

Returning:

```
192.168.101.12 -> 192.168.101.11 ==> 192.168.2.2 -> 192.168.2.15 (all port 2300)
```

I have been at this for a while and it seems like this should be straight-forward, but I am not (yet) fluent in iptables.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this ?
http://easyfwgen.morizot.net/gen/
It's quite old though, so please check the rules on a test system before applying them on a production system.

Comment: As both are on private addresses, the normal answer would be routing, not iptables. What are the routes on all three devices, they are necessary to know either way.

Comment: Thanks for your input! @RalfFriedl I am looking at routing again - keep in mind that I want only one port and that I want it to be transparent; the client has to be able to specify box as server on its subnet, and be none the wiser.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, though it is probably not the ideal solution. Using netcat:

```
mkfifo proxypipe
while true; do nc -l 9010 0<proxypipe | nc 192.168.101.12 9000 1> proxypipe; done
```

Note that I use 9010 as the server port for the client side. This nonetheless perfectly duplicates the server locally.